# How can I get input radio elements to horizontally align?

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button

I want these radio inputs to stretch across the screen, rather than one beneath the other:

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="always">Always
<br>
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="never">Never
<br>
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="costChange">Cost Change
```

CSS

```
input[type="radio"] {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/8wRT3/13/

I've monkeyed around with the display properties, and googled, and bang (bung? binged?) for an answer, but haven't found one.

Comment: You could start by removing the line breaks in between them. Then maybe try `float: left;` or something if they're still not inline.

Comment: @Chad - no need to float them, they're inline by default.

Comment: @j08691 yea, I realized I didn't say all of what I intended haha. I was thinking that he might be having an issue because of a predefined style or something, so I was saying to float it if removing the line breaks didn't work.

Comment: You really should use the label element, it helps to reduce ambiguity (which text is for which control?)

Comment: @cimmanon: Y? At the jsfiddle you can see there is no ambiguity, unless your comment is ambiguous to me.

Comment: Except they *are* ambiguous to the user once they're placed inline and once there are more of them.  Radios (and checkboxes) without labels have too small of an activation area to hit accurately for many users.

Comment: ... you *bong* for an answer ...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your case, you just need to remove the line breaks (`<br>` tags) between the elements - `input` elements are `inline-block` by default (in Chrome at least). [**(updated example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/8wRT3/14/).

```
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="always">Always
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="never">Never
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="costChange">Cost Change
```

---

I'd suggest using `<label>` elements, though. In doing so, clicking on the label will check the element too. Either associate the `<label>`'s `for` attribute with the `<input>`'s `id`: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/9000o0bc/)

```
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="always" value="always"/>
<label for="always">Always</label>

<input type="radio" name="editList" id="never" value="never"/>
<label for="never">Never</label>

<input type="radio" name="editList" id="change" value="costChange"/>
<label for="change">Cost Change</label>
```

..or wrap the `<label>` elements around the `<input>` elements directly: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLrkw05/)

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="editList" value="always"/>Always
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="editList" value="never"/>Never
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="editList" value="costChange"/>Cost Change
</label>
```

You can also get fancy and use the [`:checked` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).

Answer (score 10):

This also works like a charm

```html
<form>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3
    </label>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get your radio button to list horizontally , just add

RepeatDirection="Horizontal"

to your .aspx file where the asp:radiobuttonlist is being declared.

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wRT3/15/)

Simply remove `</br>` between input radio's

```
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="always">Always
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="never">Never
<input type="radio" name="editList" value="costChange">Cost Change
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
```