# How to align radio buttons inside a DIV?

Tags: php, html, css

Can someone please guide me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong with my CSS? I want to make my radio buttons aligned horizontally inside a DIV.

what I want:

```
|------(*)------|------|
1d     1w     1m     3m
```

thanks in advance. [here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1vLzw16/3/) for how it looks like now

map.php

```
<div id="menu_option">
        <h1>Menu Option</h1>
            <div id="button_position">


        <div id="date_selector">    
            <label>Select Date Range</label>
        <form action="show_aht2.php" method="post">
                    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1d" checked="checked"/>1d
                    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1w" />1w
                    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1m" />1m
                    <input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="3m" />3m
                    <input type="submit" name="get_aht" value="Get AHT" />
        </form>
</div><!--date selector-->

                <div class="clear"></div> 

            </div><!--button position-->
    </div><!-- end menu_option div-->
```

CSS:

```
/*menu bar option*/
#menu_option{
width:200px;
height:600px;
background:#0099FF;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
position: relative;
float:right;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center; 
}

input[type="radio"] {
margin-left:10px;
}

#date_selector{
border:3px;
border-color:black;
}

#button_position{
width: 150px;
height: 80px
position: absolute;
}

#button_position button{
font-weigth:bold;    
font-size:1.3em;
}
```

Comment: _“what I want:”_ … is unclear. Do you want actual pipe symbols and minus signs … or what? Please be more specific.

Comment: The radio buttons would automatically be on one one line – if there was enough space for that. But since you restricted the width of the `#button_position` to 150px, there isn’t – and so they naturally break into a second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you're using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) incorrectly. As you have it right now, the first `if` statement will always raise an error.

```
isset( $_POST['date_selected'] === "1d" )
```

Breaking it down, you have a comparison statement whose result is always a boolean. This is then being passed as a parameter to the `isset()` function. `isset` will then raise an error because it doesn't know how to deal with scalar values.

As for aligning the CSS buttons horizontally, please have a look at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014766/how-can-i-get-input-radio-elements-to-horizontally-align)

Comment: thank you I fixed the problem with the PHP, it was a silly mistake doing isset everywhere. I still have the problem with the CSS aligning my radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle in line 6 i dont see any method.

You put 'method=""'. The correct is 'method="post"'

Answer (score 0):

I use this always, read about this. I find this a good practice

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
     //Do the thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a lot of ways to approach sending that data to PHP, mine may not be so practical, but maybe something a little outside the box can help. If you want a lot of control over the data being sent to the posted to the PHP file, you could send it via javascript and read it from the PHP file using $*GET. I made a copy&paste example html file that you can run in the same directory as your PHP file and it should yield the results your looking for with a small amount of editing. I like this approach just because it really gives you control over the data before even sending it to the PHP file, makes coding the PHP file smaller. (Theoretically this method would give performance increase! ^*^)

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="date_selector">        
<input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1d" checked="checked"/>1d<br/>
<input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1w" />1w<br />
<input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="1m" />1m<br />
<input type="radio" name="date_selected" value="3m" />3m<br />
<button onclick="sendRadios()">Get AHT</button>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
function sendRadios() {
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var i = a.length - 1;
while (i != -1) {
if (a[i].checked == true) {
var rVal = a[i].value;
window.location.href = "./show_aht2.php?date_selected=" + rVal;
}
i = i - 1;
}
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, the above code is how to send data on a webpage to PHP through Javascript.

p.s. If using this CHANGE YOUR $_POST to $_GET