# XSL(XML) File add horizontal align in RadioButtons

Tags: .net, xml

I have a question.

I have this XSL code for radio buttons:

```
<xsl:if test="Type = 'grade'">
                            <input id="Answer.{Id}" type="radio" name="Question.{QuestionId}" value="{Value}" validate="true"></input>
                          <label for="Answer.{Id}" style="vertical-align: super;">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Value"></xsl:value-of>
                          </label>
                        </xsl:if>
```

I want to make them order like horizontal, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Input elements are inline-block by default. It seems your label elements are creating a line break which makes the radio buttons align vertically. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014766/how-can-i-get-input-radio-elements-to-horizontally-align) post for a deeper explanation.